# Can Disk Utility format an SD card with FAT32?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, sd-card, fat32

In the pulldown for "Format", there are only the following options (other than various Mac OS Extended variations): MS-DOS (FAT) and ExFAT.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Selecting "MS-DOS (FAT)" will automatically format as FAT16 or FAT32 depending on the target's size.

Comment: Don't overlook the `options` button - it's best to choose Master Boot Record as the partition format for maximum backwards compatibility. Most are already set that way but I've seen some that needed this to work well with a FAT volume.